# Swift 4: Printing out Bool optionals as either unwrapped true or false or as wrapped nil?

Tags: swift, boolean, option-type, swift4

Basically I want to print the below value as either "true", "false" or "nil". If I try just using the wrapped value I get the "nil" I want but gain the unwanted "Optional(true)" or "Optional(false). If I force unwrap the value and the value is nil I get a fatal error. I tried the below code as I've seen it work for Strings but because "nil" is not of type Bool it's not accepted. Any solutions to this?

```
var isReal: Bool?
String("Value is \(isReal ?? "nil")")
```

I'm exporting to a csv file and it's useful to know if this value is true or false or hasn't been checked yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a one-liner:

```
var isReal: Bool?
let s = "Value is \(isReal.map { String($0) } ?? "nil")"
print(s) // "Value is nil"
```

Or with a custom extension:

```
extension Optional {
    var descriptionOrNil: String {
        return self.map { "\($0)" } ?? "nil"
    }
}
```

you can do

```
var isReal: Bool?
let s = "Value is \(isReal.descriptionOrNil)"
print(s) // "Value is nil"
```

and this works with all optional types.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157522/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-r-swift-4-printing-out-bool-optionals-as-either).

Answer (score 3):

Just do an optional binding and make this:

```
if let value = isReal {
   print(value) // will either be true or false
} else {
   // isReal is nil
}
```

Comment: I'd have to split my string up then correct? I have a couple of these values that I'm appending to a string in a for loop. Is there no way of doing this with like a partial unwrapping?

Comment: Show me how the `string` looks like and I´ll have a look @ANoobSwiftly

Comment: csvFileString.append("\\(key),\\(item.url),\\(item.dateAdded),\\(item.isReal),\\(item.lowestPrice),\\(item.medianPrice),\\(item.volumeSold24Hr)\n")

Comment: I don't know what going on with some of the formatting on my screen when I posted that here but basically of the 7 variables placed into the string; 4 are optionals... 2 Doubles, a Bool and an Int.

Comment: 750,http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/252490/Rocket%20Scrap%20Salvaged%20Pickaxe,2017-10-24 11:44:08 +0000,Optional(true),Optional(2.0899999999999999),Optional(1.8600000000000001),Optional(2)

Comment: However sometimes I want the results to be nil in the csv file; to show that they haven't been gathered yet.

Comment: I don't want to unwrap into a default value; because that would make the data misleading...

Comment: Well you should do the same approach as in my example when you loop through the item: Then try to unwrap the value, if it works append the unwrapped value if it does not work then just append `nil`. Or did I misunderstand your approach?

Comment: @ANoobSwiftly you can unwrap a bunch of variables in one `if` line:

`if let var1 = var1, let var2 = var2, let var3 = var3 /*... etc. */ {`

Comment: @RashwanL I was just trying to do it in less lines of code and without creating another variable for each. I think the answer below is the one I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Although I would suggest to implement it using Optional binding as what mentioned in [Rashwan L's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933334/5501940), if you are aiming -for some reason- to declare it as one lined string, you could simply do it like this:

```
var isReal: Bool?
let myString = isReal != nil ? "Value is \(isReal!)" : "Value is nil"
```

Comment: @LeoDabus why do you think it would be better than what I mentioned? Thank you for your consideration in advance.