# Swift String/Character Optional Printing without "Optional"

Tags: swift, option-type

New to swift, and trying to print an `Optional` with String interpolation. I want it to print `nil` when the `Optional` is empty, but also want it to print the String/Character properly when it actually contains one.

So what I'm trying to accomplish should be usable here:

```
print("The result is: \(funcToReturnOptional)")
```

with the result being either the valued result or `nil` being printed.

How can I do this? I don't want to force unwrap as I'm expecting some tests of the actual function to return nil.

For the record, the function is:

```
func firstNonRepeatingChar(input:String)->Character?{
    //set a default return object
    var result: Character? = nil
    //convert input for easy and clean navigation
    let converted = Array(input)
    //set start of enumeration
    var index: Int = 0
    //set variable to compare
    var c:Character
    //should only trigger if non-empty input
    while index<converted.count-1{
        c=converted[index]
        //check for non-repeated value
        if !converted[index+1..<converted.count].contains(c){
            result=c
            return result
        }
        index+=1
    }
    return result
}
```

And I'm attempting to print like:

```
print(firstString+" should return \(firstNonRepeatingCharacter(input: firstString)??"nil")")
```

Comment: would you share `funcToReturnOptional` relevant code please

Comment: With the extension method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933890/1187415 you could do `firstNonRepeatingChar(input: firstString).descriptionOrNil`

Comment: is your code still issue ? if so what is the error?

Comment: The only issues arise when I try to use ?? or .descriptionOrNil. The former says I can't use optional chaining on non-optional type Character. The latter says Character has no member "descriptionOrNil" Edit: Oh, it was a custom extension.

Comment: @user3478947 what is your swift version?

Comment: Swift version is 3

Comment: @user3478947 I seem your code is swift2 specially this line `let converted = Array(input)`

Comment: Your code should be already working. What is the result you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is function :

```
func firstNonRepeatingChar(input:String)->Character?{
        //set a default return object
        var result: Character? = nil
        //convert input for easy and clean navigation
       // let converted = Array(input) swift2
        let converted = [Character](input.characters) //swift3
        //set start of enumeration
        var index: Int = 0
        //set variable to compare
        var c:Character
        //should only trigger if non-empty input
        while index<converted.count-1{
            c=converted[index]
            //check for non-repeated value
            if !converted[index+1..<converted.count].contains(c){
                result=c
                return result
            }
            index+=1
        }
        return result
    }
```

And calling :

```
print("The result is: \(firstNonRepeatingChar(input: "I miss you")?.description ?? "nil")")
```

output console :

> The result is: I

or

```
 let fistString = "I miss you"  
 print("here is FistString: \(fistString) and The result is: \(firstNonRepeatingChar(input: fistString)?.description ?? "nil")")
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I'm way to used to Java, optionals are just weird.

Comment: @user3478947 no man optionals has big advantages .. just keep learning swift hope you will get idea

Answer (score -1):

Swift 4

Unwraps the character optional or default to the String `nil`

```
let result = firstNonRepeatingCharacter(input: firstString)?.description ?? "nil"

print("\(firstString) should return \(result)")
```

Comment: Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type Character. Which is odd because my function does return a Character?

Comment: `func firstNonRepeatingChar(input:String)->Character?{
    var result: Character? = nil
    let converted = Array(input)
    var index: Int = 0
    var c:Character
    while index<converted.count-1{
        c=converted[index]
        if !converted[index+1..<converted.count].contains(c){
            result=c
            return result
        }
        index+=1
    }
    return result
}`

Comment: `print(firstString+"Should return \(firstNonRepeatingChar(input:firstString)")`

Comment: @user3478947 I'm confused as to how this answer was downvoted for the same answer.

Comment: I don't even know. In all honesty I kind of forgot about it when someone else down voted it. I can say for sure I chose the other one because he also corrected my array conversion for Swift 3, so technically it was more helpful